# Access DropDownList in EditItemTemplate within GridView on GridView_RowEditing

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, edititemtemplate

I inserted a DropDownList into an EditItemTemplate within a GridView and I'd like to fill this DropDownList with Items based on a Value in another GridView-Column on the same row.

Let me give you an example:

If the row looks like this:

Itemname, string, TextBox, (editbutton)

I want the click on EditButton to transform the string "TextBox" into a DropDownList with the Options "TextBox" or "DropDownList", but if the row looks like this:

Itemname, bool, CheckBox, (editbutton)

I want the DropDown to only feature "CheckBox" and "RadioButton".

So, logically, I need to access a) the Column containing the value of the datatype-field (string or bool) and b) access the DropDown-List to modify its items within the GridView_RowEditing-Event.

I already managed doing a), can anyone help me with b)?

My Code currently looks like this:

```
        protected void gridVariables_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (gridVariables.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text)
        {
            case "string":
            case "double":
            case "long":
                break;
            case "bool":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        gridVariables.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gridVariables_DataBind();
    }
```

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post the gridview code ill just do this in psuedo code

```
In your rowdatabound Event handler
Check if the row is the edit row
ddl.Items.Clear()
if (dataitem is textbox or ddl)
   ddl.items.add("textBox");
   ddl.items.add("DDL");
else
   ddl.items.add("CB");
   ddl.items.add("RB");
```

Comment: Excellent! This approach also solved another problem I've had, thanks a lot!